# Excel Help structuring data as a pivot table

Tags: excel, data-structures, pivot-table

I'm struggling to understand how to create a pivot table from raw data i have.
The reason i need to do this is so i can use the column names as slicer and further create filterable pie chart, but with the current data set i have no idea how to create pivot table.

[image: Example table]

Expected result:
Slicer for the regions and pie chart for the product groups, so when i press a region i get the revenue for the regions in the pie chart.

I hope my explanation is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i got to the conclusion that i have to restructure my data.
What i did was calculate for each product group its revenue per region.

It should look like this:

[image]

Afterwards it was easy to make the pivot table and pie chart from the pivot table, with slicer for regions.